# is it possible to change the resolucion of a video file with javascript from the front end?

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video

I have saved an MP4 video in a File type variable, is it possible to change the resolution of the video from the frontend?, without using other sources, just manipulating a single file.

try to use dashjs library but i think it works only with mpd videos.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transcode a video file on the frontend, i.e. in the browser, using a ffmpeg Javascript implementation.

The one below is well supported and includes examples of transcoding:

- https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm

This will be slower than doing it server side or than using a program on your computer but it is much faster than this type of task used to be in the browser thanks to leveraging Web Assembly language.

You do need to be aware of the need for SharedArrayBuffer support:

> Only browsers with SharedArrayBuffer support can use ffmpeg.wasm, you can check HERE for the complete list.

The link referred to above is here:
https://caniuse.com/sharedarraybuffer